# Comparison Between two array with C

Tags: c, arrays

i am working on a school problem. I am supposed to compare two arrays and find the number of mismatches and perfect matches. Example : I have Array[4]={8,4,8,8} and ArrayB[4]={4,8,8,4}. It should print out 1 perfect match and 3 mismatches. My code is like this :   . The perfect match works but mismatch does not. Please help: Mis_match means it has the SAME value but at different position in array. Perfect match means it has the SAME value and the same position in  both arrays.

```
int m,n,j;
int perfect = 0;
int mis_match=0;
for (m=0;m<4;m++)
{
  if(A[m]=B[m])
     perfect++;
     A[m]==B[m]=-1;
  else 
     for (n=0;n<4;n++)
     {
        for (j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
           if(A[n]== B[j])
           mis_match++;
           break;
         }
     }
    printf("we have %d perfect matches, %d mismatches", perfect,mis_match);
    return 0;
```

Comment: Shouldn't mismatches simply be array length - perfect matches?

Comment: 1. The comparison operator is `==`, **not** `=`.

2. You have not initialized `perfect`.

Comment: This is an unreadable mess. Format & indent properly.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a few mistakes here. First:

```
int perfect, mis_match; // need to be intialized.
```

So you have to set them to `0`.

```
int perfect = 0;
int mis_match = 0;
```

You also have to note that: `if(A[m]=B[m])` (In your first loop) should be `if(A[m]==B[m])` (You got comparison operator wrong).

In the second mismatch set, if the array size is the same, then you can simply just do `array length - matches = mismatches` Since if it's not a match, it's a mismatch.

Comment: You misunderstand the mis_match. Mis_Match mean it has the same value but at different position in stack.

Comment: @TrungNguyenHuu In that case, I guess. But I assumed the way the problem was worded, either a choice between match or mismatch. Regardless, the first bit of code still needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
int a[4] = {8,4,8,8};
int b[4] = {4,8,8,4};
int mc = 0;
for(int i=0; i < 4; ++i)
  if (a[i] == b[i])
    ++mc;
printf("we have %d perfect matches, %d mismatches", mc, 4 - mc);
```

Comment: What about a recursive version?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever I understand you need not to use any nested loops it increases the time complexity. I think it simply.
Here is the code--

```
int main(){
int A[4] = {8,4,8,8};
int B[4] = {4,8,8,4};
int perfect = 0;
int mis_match = 0;
for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ){
    if( A[i] == B[i] )
        perfect++;
    else
        mis_match++;
}

printf("we have %d perfect matches, %d mismatches", perfect,mis_match);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to initialize the variable `mis_match` to `0`. You do not even need this variable actually. You just check each element of the first array with each element of the second array and increment  `perfect` if they match. Then calculate the difference between the size of the array and `perfect`. That is the number of mismatches.
 Your modified code should look like this

```
int perfect=0,m=4;
int A[4]={8,4,8,8},B[4]={4,8,8,4};
for(i=0;i<m;i++)   
{
    if(A[i]==B[i])  
        perfect++;
}
printf("We have %d perfect matches and %d mismatches",perfect,m-perfect);
```

You have used `if(A[m]=B[m])`, which is wrong. This statement will assign the value of`B[m]` in `A[m]` instead of checking whether they are equal. You need to use the `==` operator to check their equality.